# Why DataInputStream can't read char correctly?

Tags: kotlin, eofexception

I tried to  write String in  DataInputStream, when read from DataInputStream single char, but I have an error.

I expected, that `readChar()` return 'q', but method:

```
assertEquals('q', DataInputStream("q".byteInputStream(Charsets.UTF_8)).readChar())
```

Throws exception:

> java.io.EOFException
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readChar(DataInputStream.java:365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [`DataInput.readChar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html#readChar()) which states:

> Reads two input bytes and returns a char value. Let `a` be the first byte read and `b` be the second byte. The value returned is:
>
> ```
> (char)((a << 8) | (b & 0xff))
> ```
>
> This method is suitable for reading bytes written by the [`writeChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutput.html#writeChar(int)) method of interface [`DataOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataOutput.html).

The last sentence is basically also the solution. If you write the data using `writeChar`, reading works as expected, i.e. the following will give you a succeeding test case:

```
assertEquals('q', DataInputStream(ByteArrayOutputStream().apply {
                    DataOutputStream(this).use {
                      it.writeChars("q")
                    }
                  }.toByteArray().inputStream())
                  .readChar())
```

The following, even though not mentioned in the interface, may also work out:

```
assertEquals('q', DataInputStream("q".byteInputStream(Charsets.UTF_16BE)).readChar())
```